# Acumatica REST API - How To Include Extended Data when retrieving Stockitem

Tags: rest, acumatica, acumatica-kb

I need to retrieve Stockitems and all fields (including "Extended Data") I don't see a way of doing it via the REST API. There is nothing to Expand that I can see, and SELECT doesn't seem to help either.

[image: Screenshot Stockitem]

I am guessing I will need to extend the existing endpoint since the default endpoint for stock items does not show the extended data as an expandable item. Is that right?

However, how can I know how to find the extended data? I inspect the element, but it doesn't tell me much.

[image: Inspection Screenshot]

How would I include the right information in an endpoint so I can expand it via the REST API? Or how do I access Extended Data via the REST API?

Comment: What have you tried and failed? Specifically, have you tried using [$custom](https://help-2019r2.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=c5e2f36a-0971-4b33-b127-3c3fe14106ff) query option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am guessing I will need to extend the existing endpoint since the
>   default endpoint for stock items does not show the extended data as an
>   expandable item. Is that right?

Yes that's right.

> However, how can I know how to find the extended data? I inspect the
>   element, but it doesn't tell me much.

It tells you the data view (ItemSettings) and the custom field (UsrAm) which you need to add in the extended endpoint.

First create the extended endpoint then select the entity (StockItem) in that extended endpoint. Select fields tab item, extend the entity and use populate to add custom fields (UsrAm) from the target data view (ItemSettings)

[image]

Comment: @ Hugues Beauséjour:  Thank you so much! This worked and I accepted it. But I was wondering, instead of extending this as a new endpoint, could I just add an entity and select these fields, leaving the rest of the StockItems endpoint in place?

Comment: Making any kind of changes to endpoint requires extending. You need to retrieve StockItem so logically it is the entity to use. You can map another entity but I see no reason why one might take the long road here. In other words you want an orange so it makes sense to pick an orange rather than get an apple.